# deployed django webpage using apache and mode_wsgi doesnt show other pages aside from index.html

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I am totally new to the world of Django, I recently tried to deploy my website on production server and I have been successful to some extent. I deployed the website on a windows base VPS, using apache and mode_wsgi. the webpage is up and running, I can  view it on localhost, the problem is when I try to show other pages of the website like "localhost/about", it gives me
"
Not Found
The requested resource was not found on this server.
"
does anybody had the same issue?
any help in how to solve it would be much appreciated

Comment: Are you running the application on port 80 or any other port?

Comment: Yes, I'm runjng it on port 80, and I also opend port 80 on firewall

Comment: Without any code, how can we help? :-) Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)